# TextView changes for short time then changes back

Tags: android, button, textview

I have a function that when a button is clicked the TextView changes to something different.  My issue is that the TextView is changing (I want to eat the apple) but only for a few milliseconds then it changes back to what it was before (I want to eat). Can anyone tell me why this is?

Java File:

```
public class EatOptions extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eatoptions);

    TextView eat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eatbanner);
    eat.setText("I want to eat");
}

public void apple (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EatOptions.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    TextView finalBanner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eatbanner);
    finalBanner.setText("I want to eat the apple");

    }
  }
```

LogCat error each time button is clicked:

```
07-30 17:44:22.276: W/ResourceType(11368): Failure getting entry for 0x01080a03 (t=7 e=2563) in package 0 (error -75)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is changing because you are restarting the `Activity` every time you click on the button

Remove

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, EatOptions.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```